# How do I go "back" in Shotwell?

Tags: shotwell

When I browse through a long list of events and then double-click an event to view its photos, how do I get back to where I was in the list of events so I can continue browsing?

My usage pattern is this (though on the scale of about a thousand more events):

1. Glance at event #1 thumbnail.
2. Glance at event #2 thumbnail.
3. Glance at event #3 thumbnail.
4. Glance at event #4 thumbnail.
5. Glance at event #5 thumbnail.
6. Peruse event #6 photos.
7. Glance at event #7 thumbnail.
8. Glance at event #8 thumbnail.
9. Peruse event #9 photos.
10. Glance at event #10 thumbnail.
11. Glance at event #11 thumbnail.
12. Glance at event #12 thumbnail.
13. Glance at event #13 thumbnail.
14. Peruse event #14 photos.

I'm not sure how to go from step 6 to 7 and from step 9 to 10.

Answer (score 3):

I know, the question is pretty old, but I had the same question recently.

Double-сlicking a photo returns to the photo browser.

Comment: This is great! Been clicking on "last import" and then the event I was in, for years. Thanks.